# Can't get JavaScript Accordion to Work Correctly With SQL Server Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql-server

I am using an ASP Repeater to display content from an SQL Server table.

I have been trying to combine [this](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-modern-business/blob/master/faq.html) template and [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Accordion-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) tutorial.

The output is rendering as expected below:

[image: screenshot]

However, when I click on any date, only the 1st item is expanding.
Below is my aspx code, and the JavaScript scripts.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordian" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="collapseOne">
                                                    <%# Eval("News_Date") %>
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <%# Eval("News_Content") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>

       <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the working example which I am trying to modify:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Item One Heading</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Item One Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Item Two Heading</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Item Two Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Item Three Content</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           Item Three Content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see above, the href of the links and ID's of the div's both increment by one, as div's are added.

My code is only affecting the first item because of the href="collapseOne".

I think I need to find a way to increment based on the number of items I will be displaying in the repeater, but I'm not sure how to progress

I have inspected the elements and this is what I have found:

[image: accordionInspect]

Below is the HTML output after changes made:
[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for C# Asp.Net

**Your Page**

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAccordian" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= getIndex() %>">
                            <%# Eval("News_Date") %>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <!-- Get the current index-->
                <div id="collapse<%=getIndex()%>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <%# Eval("News_Content") %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--then increment it for the next repeater element-->
            <% incrementIndex(); %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
       <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
int index;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    index = 1;
}

protected int getIndex()
{
    return index;
}
protected void incrementIndex()
{
    index++;
}
```

**EDIT**

I was wrong about the script blocks. I should have used `<%= %>` when I want to return a value to the page and `<% %>` to simply run code.

Comment: I've copied your solution in instead of my repeater, and added the Code Behind. But when I run the project, I'm getting a number of Error's: I'm told that there are a number of ')' and ';' expected on the ASPX page on the lines where you entered %#getIndex(); and incrementIndex(); %

Comment: I've looked further and there are errors due to the semi-colon's after getIndex() and incrementIndex() in the div tags. I've removed the semi-colons in the first div, which removes this error. But when I remove the first semi colon on this "<div id="collapse<%#getIndex(); incrementIndex(); %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">" line, I get an error as it is needed before the incrementIndex()

Comment: The other problem was that `<%= %>` and `<% %>` are the only ones that were needed.

Comment: I've updated my page with your edited code. The "News_Date"'s are appearing in the header tags. But when I click on any of them, nothing is expanded within the accordion.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change :(

Comment: I think the div where id="accordian" is meant to hold all the items. I don't think that div is meant to be within the repeater

Comment: I moved that div to encase the repeater and reverted to `id="accordian"`
Maybe this time?

Comment: I've just had a thought. I know we changed the href of the links from collapseOne to collapse1, etc. to allow for the increment. Could that be the reason it is not working?

Comment: How does your generated HTML compare to the sample you provided?

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of how the HTML is generating when I paste your latest suggestion

Comment: Also, I replaced your href="collapse<%= getIndex() %>" and div id="collapse<%=getIndex()%>" with collapseOne in both, to see if they would work, but it made no difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132343/discussion-between-bobjoe-and-sweg).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions applicable to many HTML and JavaScript / jQuery issues.

1) Review the generated HTML using Inspect or View Source to ensure that it is both valid HTML and defined as needed for the feature you are trying to implement.

2) Insert JavaScript **alert** statements (temporarily) to provide feedback as to how much of your JavaScript and jQuery is being executed. Many JavaScript and jQuery problems are due to an upstream issue that prevents the execution of the downstream code.

These suggestions alone may not fix your problem, but they should give you more feedback to help you do so.

Comment: thanks, I've since inspected the code, and found no errors with the JavaScript or jQuery. My problem is that multiple div's have the same ID, and are referencing the first item in the accordion, rather than their specified item

Comment: You have multiple div's with the same Id's because inside your repeater, you always use the same ID `<div id="collapseOne"` & `<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">`
In other words, each time the ASP Repeater generates an element, it uses those ids

Comment: @bobjoe Hi, I realise that I am only affecting the first div in the repeater because each div has an id="collapseOne". I have added additional information/code above to show the working example which I am trying to adapt. In the working example, the div of each item is incremented (i.e. collapseTwo, collapseThree, etc.) But I'm not sure how to increment this through the repeater. Do you have any thoughts, as I think this would fix my problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have added an example using c# script blocks to handle incrementing the ID's.